# Appearance of a list but this is a string

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

## Explaination

I'm using psycopg2 to store my results and to recover them. I'm storing a list like this in my table :

```
["Building configuration...\n\nCurrent configuration : 233 bytes\n!\ninterface FastEthernet0/24\n", "Building configuration...\n\nCurrent configuration : 235 bytes\n!\ninterface GigabitEthernet0/1\n"]
```

When I do a SELECT on this table, here is the output :

```
[('["Building configuration...\\n\\nCurrent configuration : 233 bytes\\n!\\ninterface FastEthernet0/24\\n", "Building configuration...\\n\\nCurrent configuration : 235 bytes\\n!\\ninterface GigabitEthernet0/1\\n"]',)]
```

I have a string in a tuple, in a list... :

```
test = [('["Building configuration...\\n\\nCurrent configuration : 233 bytes\\n!\\ninterface FastEthernet0/24\\n", "Building configuration...\\n\\nCurrent configuration : 235 bytes\\n!\\ninterface GigabitEthernet0/1\\n"]',)]

print(type(test))
test = test[0]
print(type(test))
for om in test:
    print(type(om))

out:
<class 'list'>
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'str'>
```

I would like to browse through the list (which is currently a string) and have a result like this :

```
print(test[0])
>>> Building configuration...
Current configuration : 233 bytes
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
```

```
print(test[1])
>>> Building configuration...
Current configuration : 235 bytes
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
```

I don't know how to do this. It's hard to explain the problem, hope you understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the string inside the tuple and the list, then split on `", "`. You could also strip the ends:

```
test = test[0][0]  # get the string
test = test.strip('["')
test = test.strip('"]')
test_list = test.split('", "')

for t in test_list:
    print(t)
```

Comment: it's working thank you, but is it possible to transform this string in a list ?